# How to test nested service call containing SwitchMap

Tags: angular, angular-test

I have a two service call nested on service component and I am using the swithcMap for it. Code is something like like below which works perfectly fine but unit test is not working. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong on unit testing?

```
myService():Observable<HttpResponse<any>>{
   return this.http.get<string>(this.firstURL)
      .pipe(
          switchMap(res1 =>{
          return this.http.get<any>(res1['val1']['val2']);
         }
      })
}
```

For testing above code I have something like this

```
it('should call http', () => {
   serv.myService().subscribe(res =>
      expect(res.val).toBe(100)
   )

var req = httpMockServ.expectOne('testUrl');
req.flush({val:10});

});
```

Looks like it is not mocking the second http call. I am getting can not read property val2 of undefined.

Comment: Not only **you**'re not mocking the second http call, but you're returning an object from the first one which has a single property `val`, and the service needs to get the `val2` property of the property `val1` of this object. Since there is no such val1 property, that fails.